# Magento 2.2.8 Error After Update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, command-line

have in local a Clone of my site online, have update with composer from 2.2.8 to 2.3.2, have reproduced all steps from Magento 2 Guide
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

only after have execute the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade
show me this Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ves_blog_post in var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php online 152 .....
```

anyone have idea/suggestions how to solve this problem?
Thank anyway

Comment: you need to ask extension developer. your database table `ves_blog_post` missing or have typo

Comment: Disable the blog extension and try it again.